# How to tell Protractor to use hash in baseUrl globally?

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-test

Currently, HashLocationStrategy is enabled in my Angular App, and when I run

```
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + '/login');
```

in my e2e spec, I receive following error:

> - Expected 'http://localhost:49152/#/login' to be 'http://localhost:49152/login'.

Is there a way to tell Protractor to use hash suffix in `baseUrl` globally?

Comment: what is the problem to correct your expectation: browser.baseUrl + '/#/login'

Answer (score 1):

You can define **baseUrl** in your *config file Or pass parameter* from command line or *Jenkins* so that it would be available to all specs.

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumServerJar: '../../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar',
    specs: ['../spec/*.js'],
    framework:'jasmine2',
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:49152/#/"
}
```

And can check expectation,

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + 'login');
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(browser.baseUrl + 'login');
```

Or if you pass parameter from command line,

```
protractor --baseUrl='http://localhost:49152/#/' protractor.conf.js
```