# Angular 7: can't change baseUrl in protractor (router uses hash)

Tags: angular, protractor

I've tried changing the baseUrl in protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/#',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

But no matter what I do, I can't get it to work. I've tried navigating in my Page Object by passing a relative url:

```
browser.get('/authentication/sign-up');
```

but the baseUrl it's appended to is still the default `http://localhost:4200`, instead of `http://localhost:4200/#`

Comment: What happens if you add an extra slash after the hash? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53126284/10747134

Comment: Same thing. I've actually logged browser.baseUrl. That's why I know it's not getting the baseUrl from the protractor.conf.js file.

Comment: I wonder if including the tsconfig will overwrite that config option? What happens when you change the baseUrl in the tsconfig.e2e.json (or add the prop since I think the default is in the tsconfig.json extended by tsconfig.e2e)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, @Christian did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Add `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` to your config file and keep `baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',`

```
onPrepare() {
 browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this with one of the apps i was writing tests against.  The short answer is to use the driver directly like this:

```js
browser.driver.get('someUrl')
```

This will more than likely trigger an alert generated by the browser, which can be dismissed by the driver as well like the below code:

```js
const alertObject = browser.driver.switchTo().alert();
await alertObject.accept();
```

hope this helps